# Rails＋Angular＋GruntをHerokuデプロイ

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, heroku

Railsを勉強して半年の初心者なのですが、
こちらの記事（http://qiita.com/hkusu/items/b34f684b49751d9c9abd）を参考に
APIサーバを Rails、フロントエンドを AngularJS で開発し、Gruntで自動化を考えているのですが、HerokuでRailｓとGruntを使用したwebアプリをデプロイできるのでしょうか。

またHerokuでのデプロイが難しいようであれば、手軽にデプロイできるのはどのような方法になるでしょうか。

お手数ですが、教えていただけないでしょうか。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

RailsとGruntを使用したウェブアプリをHerokuにデプロイするのは以下の記事を見る限り出来るように思われます。

- [Angular/Railsシングルページアプリケーション(SPA)をHerokuにデプロイする](http://qiita.com/icb54615/items/e5d4db164c5002e4b183)
- [How to Deploy an Angular/Rails Single-Page Application to Heroku](http://www.angularonrails.com/deploy-angular-rails-single-page-application-heroku/)

Comment: ありがとうございます！
こちらで試してみます